# How can K-Means clustering work without spacial information?

Tags: image, distance, rgb, k-means

Possibly a short one. Just got stuck at working with K-Means Clustering.

I have looked up this python/skimage commands:

```
image_array = image.reshape([-1,3]).astype(np.float32)
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=0).fit(image_array)
labels_array = kmeans.labels_
labels = labels_array.reshape([image.shape[0], image.shape[1]])
```

when I noticed that the RGB images hast to be converted to one long array. 
How can k-means clustering know about the 2 spacial dimensions (and the 3th one - color) when I pass an array?

Or is just my assumption wrong that spacial information is needed? At least the goal is to minimize the within-cluster sum of squares. The distance in x, y and color direction is therefor important, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I assumed a one dimensional array is returned. Instead a three dimensional is returned by the reshaping. Positional information is indeed not used in this example of K-Means.